# BeginForm and AttributeRouting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper, attributerouting

I am having trouble figuring out or understanding how to make my routing work as i would like it to work in my project.

I have the following form in a view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "Aanbod", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <div class="filterBarComponent">
        <div class="dropdownContainer">
            @Html.DropDownList("Merk", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Merken)), "-- Kies Merk")
        </div>
        <div class="dropdownContainer">
            @Html.DropDownList("Brandstof", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Brandstoffen)), "-- Kies Brandstof")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filterBarComponent">
        <div>
            <label for="sliderPrijs">Maximum Prijs</label>
            <input id="sliderPrijs"  name="prijs"
                   type="range"
                   min="100" max="100000"
                   step="100" value="@ViewBag.prijs"
                   oninput="outputUpdatePrijs(value)"
                   class="slider">
            <output for="sliderPrijs" id="prijs"></output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="sliderKm">Kilometer Stand</label>
            <input id="sliderKm" name="km"
                   type="range"
                   min="0" max="500000"
                   step="10000" value="@ViewBag.km"
                   oninput="outputUpdateKilometers(value)"
                   class="slider">
            <output for="SliderKm" id="kmStand"></output>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="filterBarComponent">
        <input type="submit" value="Zoeken" class="filterbutton"/>
    </div>
    }
```

The form leads to this controller action.

```
[Route("filter/{km}/{prijs}/{merk}/{brandstof}/{page}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Filter( int km, int prijs, Merken merk = Merken.AlleMerken, Brandstoffen brandstof = Brandstoffen.AlleBrandstoffen, int page = 0 )
        {
           ....

        }
```

My Url is always `/filter?Merk=&Brandstof=&prijs=25000&km=250000`
While i want to achieve this `/filter/10000/5600/2/1`

Is it possible to do this while using forms?
If so, how? if not, what should i do as alternative?

Comment: A browser knows nothing about your server side route definitions. A `FormMethod.Get` will always add the values of your form controls as query string values (you would need to build your own `url` and use javascript - `location.href=yourUrl;` - to redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thx, browsing through your answers, i found a similar question in it. Marking my own as duplicate.